# How can I automate my python script to run again after every time it finished?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduler

I'm recording a video with motion detection using Python. All motions detected in that recording will be saved into a single mp4 file. The code goes like:

```
import cv2, time
import os
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

FILE_OUTPUT = "video_" + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'))
sdThresh = 10
cv2.namedWindow('frame')
cv2.namedWindow('dist')
i = 0

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
output = cv2.VideoWriter(FILE_OUTPUT + ".mp4", fourcc, 10.0, (640,480))


t0 = time.time()

def distMap(frame1, frame2):
# outputs pythagorean distance between two frames
    frame1_32 = np.float32(frame1)
    frame2_32 = np.float32(frame2)
    diff32 = frame1_32 - frame2_32
    norm32 = np.sqrt(diff32[:,:,0]**2 + diff32[:,:,1]**2 + diff32[:,:,2]**2)/np.sqrt(255**2 + 255**2 + 255**2)
    dist = np.uint8(norm32*255)
    return dist


camera = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:@camera_ip')


check1, frame1 = camera.read()
check2, frame2 = camera.read()


while True:
# frame object
    check3, frame3 = camera.read()
    gerakan = False
    if check3 == True:
    # mirroring kamera biar gak kebalik
        frame3 = cv2.flip(frame3,1)

        rows, cols, _ = np.shape(frame3)
        dist = distMap(frame1, frame3)

        frame1 = frame2
        frame2 = frame3

   
        mod = cv2.GaussianBlur(dist, (9,9), 0)


        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(mod, 100, 255, 0)

        _, stDev = cv2.meanStdDev(mod)

        cv2.imshow("Merekam", frame2)
   
    else:
        break

    if stDev > sdThresh:
        image = cv2.resize(frame2, (640, 480))
        output.write(image)
        gerakan = True



    t1 = time.time()  # current time
    duration = t1 - t0  # diff
    if duration > 60:
        break
    elif cv2.waitKey(25) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

camera.release()

output.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

if you put attention to the **if stdDev > if stdThresh:**
that is the code for saving every motion detected to a single file.

and the **if duration > 60** shows that the code will work only for 60 seconds. after 60secs, the code will exit.

how can I automate the code to run again after every time it exits?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shell script to run your python that wait and loop